# how to display percentage on label c#

Tags: c#, mysql, winforms, windows-store-apps

how can i show the percentage on the textblock(label) in the windows store application?
how can i make it update and display a percentage on the form according to the values being set?

```
private void Button_add_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            int cls, atnd, prcent;

            cls = int.Parse(totClsInput.Text);
            atnd = int.Parse(attendedClsInput.Text);
            prcent = atnd * 100 / cls;
            attndPercentageInput.Text = prcent.ToString();

            string Query = @"INSERT INTO `bcasdb`.`tbl_attend`
                (`tbl_subject_sub_id`,
                `reg_id`,
                `total_classes`,
                `attend_classes`,
                `percentage`)
                VALUES ("
               + this.subIDInput.Text + ",'"
               + this.stdRegIdInput.Text + "','"
               + this.totClsInput + "','"
               + this.attendedClsInput + "','"
               + this.attndPercentageInput + "')";
            //This is command class which will handle the query and connection object.
            MySqlConnection conn = new MySqlConnection(BCASApp.DataModel.DB_CON.connection);
            MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand(Query, conn);
            MySqlDataReader MyReader;
            conn.Open();
            MyReader = cmd.ExecuteReader();// Here our query will be executed and data saved into the database.           
            conn.Close();
            successmsgBox();
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            errormsgBox();
        }
    }
```

Comment: What does this have to do with windows store applications?  Is attndPercentageInput.Text your problem area?  What is your current outcome vs the expected outcome?

Comment: i want to show the percentage on attndPercentageInput.Text before i click on the add button

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you need to update a label prior to an add action being taken, then your calculation logic should not be in the "add action" event handler.

You could set a `LostFocus` (not sure exactly what it's called in winforms) event handler for both your `totClsInput` and `attendedClsInput` which then both call a calculate percentage function.  Something like this:

```
protected void totClsInput_LostFocus(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    this.CalculatePercent();
}

protected void attendedClsInput_LostFocus(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    this.CalculatePercent();
}

private void CalculatePercent()
{
    int cls, atnd, prcent;

    if (totClsInput.Text != string.Empty && attendedClsInput.Text != string.Empty)
    {

        cls = int.Parse(totClsInput.Text);
        atnd = int.Parse(attendedClsInput.Text);
        prcent = atnd * 100 / cls;
        attndPercentageInput.Text = prcent.ToString();

    }
}
```

Comment: is it lost focus in C#

Comment: this method is making errors until give the second value(totClsInput.Text)

Comment: I updated the answer, note that this isn't taking into account bad data entry and probably other things. I was just trying to provide a way to get around your immediate problem :P

Comment: yeah its work but not with lostfocus its work with selectionchanged